# Neo4j fulltext search: count number of results and return limited subset

Tags: neo4j, cypher, full-text-search, neo4j-apoc

I want to count the number of results possibly returned by fulltext search, but return only a limited subset of these results. This query will return only 10 nodes and the number of all results:

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes($indexName, $searchTerm) YIELD node, score
WITH count(*) as countResults, collect({node: node, score: score})[0..10] as nodes 
RETURN nodes, countResults
```

I have two questions regarding this query:

1. Will the aggregation `count(*) as countResults` consume all rows from `db.index.fulltext.queryNodes()` and therefore, cause a build up in memory of all results?
2. Would it be better to use the APOC function [apoc.agg.slice()](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/overview/apoc.agg/apoc.agg.slice/) instead of `collect()[0..10]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO answer your questions;  1) yes, it will count the number of rows in the full text search; depending on the number of rows to be returned, it may or may not cause an issue on your memory.  2) yes, apoc.agg.slice() is better than collect()[0..10] because slice will only accumulate n results that you put rather than collecting ALL rows then getting the first 10 items.

Comment: Regarding the *1)* what I actually meant was: I only need the first 10 results from the full text search. It would be nice to know the total number of results, but only if it doesn't need to read all nodes. I was hoping the size of the returned nodes could be determined by `count(*)` in a more efficient way than that. 
If I understand it correctly, if I remove the aggregation via `count(*)` and use `apoc.agg.slice(node, 0, 10)` instead of `collect()[0..10]`, it will only aggregate 10 nodes and then return the result?

Comment: yes, it will only aggregate 10 nodes and then return the result as per documentation on apoc slice.